# Can I somehow remove header from OkHttp response before it has cached?

Tags: android, cache-control, okhttp

I cant control server, and it constantly response to me with `Cache-Control: no-cache` header. But I want to force OkHttp to cache that response regardless.

Can I somehow remove header from OkHttp response before it has cached?

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed rewrite the Cache-Control headers for responses, thus allowing OkHttp to cache it. From the Recipes on their site ( https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors )

```java
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=60")
        .build();
  }
};
```

Just add this as a network interceptor using client.addNetworkInterceptor().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scrub out the `no-cache` header, but you can still get some caching through conditional GETs.

From OkHttp's [Cache-Control](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/CacheControl.html#noCache%28%29) docs:

> In a response, this field's name "no-cache" is misleading. It doesn't prevent us from caching the response; it only means we have to validate the response with the origin server before returning it. We can do this with a conditional GET.

The `no-cache` doesn't prevent the response from being stored! When OkHttp later attempts to use that cached response, it will validate that the cached response is still good by contacting the origin server with an `If-Modified-Since` header. If the server returns `304 Not Modified`, the response body is served from the cache.

You can increase your chances of a cache hit by adding a max-stale to your request headers. This one will cause it to use the cache for responses that expired as many as 365 days ago.

```
Cache-Control: max-stale=31536000
```

Comment: I cant call server for 304 since in some cases I use cached responses for "no internet" situations.
Yes, I'm already using 4 week interval for max-stale property in cache-control.

Comment: Hi, how do I addHeaders("If-Modified-Since", value);  I checked your github website, but didn't get how to set the value, can you please give me an example? Thanks!